# TinyMCE4: How to change Enter key functionality to Shift + Enter key?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

On pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in TinyMCE4 a new paragraph is created. Is there any way to change the configuration of TinymCE4 so that <kbd>Enter</kbd> should work like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>?

On a press of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, I want a `<br/>` tag instead of a `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed an option for that mentioned in the documentation:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block

***Note that eliminating block elements is generally a "very bad idea" as many other actions in the editor really only work when the content is organized into blocks. Use this at your own risk.***

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's an option for that. It's `forced_root_block`.

From the [docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/configuration/Configuration3x@forced_root_block):

> This option enables you to make sure that any non block elements or
> text nodes are wrapped in block elements. For example something will
> result in output like: `<p><strong>something</strong></p>`. This option
> is enabled by default as of 3.0a1.
>
> **If you set this option to false
> it will never produce p tags on enter or automatically it will instead
> produce `br` elements and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will produce a `p`.**

You should also note the caveat from the docs, though:

> Note that not using `p` elements as root block can severely cripple the
> functionality of the editor.

Comment: Link to `forced_root_block` is now https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block . Did not see how turning it off limits the functionality unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [forced_root_block](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block). Probably don't though - it's most likely going to break a lot of things.